# How do you add variables to the layout and be accessible on all pages in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have some function to count data and want to showing at blade template . but i have a problem . 
this variable just working in 1 view and didnt not working in another view because i NOT parsing this variable on another view . So how i can set this variable count to all view ?

this is ilustration script :

```
 public function inventaris_baru()
{

    $user_id = null;
    $unit        = User::where('roles_id' , 1)->pluck('nama_unit', 'id'); 


    $alat    = Alat::with('users')
    ->where('jenis' ,'Alkes')
    ->where('is_active',  'false')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

    $count = $alat->count();

    return view('sarpras.inventaris_baru',['unit' => $unit, 'user_id' => $user_id ,'alat' => $alat ,'count' => $count]);
}
```

on this blade in layout

```
 <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{{route('inventaris_baru')}}" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Inventaris Baru <span class="badge badge-danger right"> {{$count}} </span></p>
                </a>
              </li>
```

this $count only work in the view **sarpras.inventaris_baru** , how i can set global and can parse this on the **layouts ?**

can someone give me best way to this ?

Comment: You can use view composer as mentioned in this tutorial https://scotch.io/tutorials/sharing-data-between-views-using-laravel-view-composers

Comment: i think its not best way , and so dificult i think .

Comment: I have seen some laravel experts like JeffreyWay using this :) There could be many other options as other answer suggest to use session, middleware or helper function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store it in session and be able to access it to your all views. like this one

```
public function inventaris_baru()
{

    $user_id = null;
    $unit        = User::where('roles_id' , 1)->pluck('nama_unit', 'id'); 


    $alat    = Alat::with('users')
    ->where('jenis' ,'Alkes')
    ->where('is_active',  'false')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

    $count = $alat->count();
    session(['count' =>  $count]);

    return view('sarpras.inventaris_baru',['unit' => $unit, 'user_id' => $user_id ,'alat' => $alat ,'count' => $count]);
}
```

Access it to your views like this

```
<li class="nav-item">
       <a href="{{route('inventaris_baru')}}" class="nav-link">
           <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
           <p>Inventaris Baru <span class="badge badge-danger right"> {{session('count')}} </span></p>
        </a>
</li>
```

Comment: its still Undefined variable: count if i open another page

Comment: trigger again the function inventaris_baru to set the session

Comment: u mean i need to trigger on all page on my controller ?

Comment: @AdhikMulat Be careful when using this answer, because although it will work, if you forgot to manually call the function on every page then the count will not be updated. Other answers involving view composer, middleware, or service provider is a safer choice if you need data accuracy

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this but i personally would create a [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/middleware) that will do the count and put the result in the session.

Edit:

An example on your case would be:

1. Create Middleware using command `php artisan make:middleware CalculateInventarisBaruCount`
2. In the handle function of the new middleware add your count logic then before `return $next($request)` you would add `session()->put('inventoris_baru_count',$count)`
3. Register your middleware by adding `\App\Http\Middleware\CalculateInventarisBaruCount::class` to the `$middleware` array in your Kernel ( i believe default location should be at `app\Http\Kernel.php`) file
4. Use the count in your layout by using `{{session('inventoris_baru_count',-1)}}`. I added -1 as a default value so you would know if something goes wrong.

Comment: u mean i need to create this function in the middleware ?

Comment: @AdhikMulat I have updated the answer to give you a simple step by step example. You should read the middleware documentation to understand how it works better especially the [Registering Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/middleware#registering-middleware) section if you need this count to only be shared on certain routes!

Comment: how if i joining this session to my middleware ? so i dont need creare a new middleware

Comment: Yes that could work! But I would suggest having one middleware do one specific thing.

Comment: i have Undefined variable :inventoris_baru_count

Comment: that looks like you are calling it incorrectly in the view. in your layout you should do `{{session('inventoris_baru_count',-1)}}`, this way even if something is wrong in your middleware your view should still say -1. Make sure there is NO `$inventoris_baru_count` anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Laravel View composer. I hope, this link will help you - https://scotch.io/tutorials/sharing-data-between-views-using-laravel-view-composers

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper file

Create a function that you can call globally.

```
if (! function_exists('yourCount')) {
    function yourCount()
    {
         $alat = Alat::with('users')
            ->where('jenis' ,'Alkes')
            ->where('is_active',  'false')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

         return $alat->count();
    }
}
```

In your blade:

```
 <p>Inventaris Baru <span class="badge badge-danger right"> {{ yourCount() }} </span></p>
```

Read [here](https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers) to setup your helper file.